# Javascript add class to selected text, not first occurrence of the selected text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to add a class (and later on to send that string to php) to a text with javascript. Whenever I try to do that, the code is adding the class to the first occurrence of my selection, not to the actual selection. Keep in mind that I want to send that EXACT selection to php (and put it in a database as well so it keep that class even after refresh).

JQ

```
    $("#highlight").click(function(){
   paraval = $('#para').html();
   sel = window.getSelection();
   newst = '<a class="selectedText">' + sel + '</a>';
   newvalue = paraval.replace(sel, newst);
   $('#para').html(newvalue);
});
```

HTML

```
    <p>Will only highlight if text is selected from comment class div only</p>
<div class="comment" id="para" contenteditable="true">Here goes some text Here goes some text Here goes some text Here goes some text
Some other text</div>
<input type="button" value="Highlight" id="highlight"/>
```

CSS

```
 .selectedText{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.comment{
    border: solid 2px;
}

.comment::selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/3/

try to select the last occurrence of the word "text". the first one will get the class "selectedText"...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call me lazy, but if you don't mind span being you selection marker tag, you can use [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/)'s cssApplier class.

```
var cssApplier;
$(document).ready(function() {
   rangy.init();
    cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier(
                 "selectedText", {normalize: true,
                                 applyToEditableOnly:true});
});

$("#highlight").click(function(){
    if(cssApplier != undefined)
    {
        cssApplier.toggleSelection();        
    }
});
```

I use `applyToEditableOnly` here to make it only work in that specific div.  (I'm not sure how cross-browser compatible that particular setting is.  Worked in Chrome and Firefox though.) This uses position rather than selection text to decide what to mark.

JS Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last occurence with lastIndexOf() and proceed like this:

```
$("#highlight").click(function(){
  paraval = $('#para').text();
  sel = "text";
   var n = paraval.lastIndexOf(sel); 
   var before = paraval.substring(0,n);
  newst = before + '<a class="selectedText">' + sel + '</a>';
  newvalue = paraval.replace(paraval, newst);
  $('#para').html(newvalue);
 });
```

Just created a fiddle for it: [Replacing last occurence](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/h7q41bog/)

Note: This quick example is only working because the word you want to highlight is at the last position of the text, but you can check out if this solution is ok for your request. In case the last occurence of the word is elsewhere, just create a variable "after" that contains the text following the last occurence of the word to the end.

Have just provided an example for this in updated fiddle: [Replacing last occurence update](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/h7q41bog/1/)

with following update to previous code:

```
var after = paraval.substring(n + sel.length, paraval.length);
newst = before + '<a class="selectedText">' + sel + '</a>' + after;
```

Comment: I said "text" as an example. Not that specific word... it should work for ANY word

Comment: @MariusS Sure, no problem. Just call the function with the word you want to replace as parameter and inside the function use the value of the parameter for the "sel". It was just considered a static example.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic. The word to be replaced is a word selected with your mouse

Comment: @MariusS Ok, wasn't clear with the question. But at least you found an answer working for you.